# How to convert a list of data frames to a panel in python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel

Given a list of data frames with the following format:

```
id  age  weight  score  date 
01  11   50      90     2011-01-23
01  12   52      89     2012-03-23
...
```

Please note that the `id` in a data frame is same. And I wish to get a panel, integrating all the data frames in the list, and with the columns `['age', 'weight', 'score']` as `item-axis`, and `date` as `major-axis`, and `id` as `minor-axis`. Do you know how to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kartik I am stuck in the indexing. According to the [documents](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-dataframe-using-to-panel-method), I should construct a multi index. But I dont't know how to construct it properly.

Comment: Oh, that's the complicated way. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to `concat` your frames together:

```
 concated = pd.concat(list_of_frames)
```

Then, you can simply:

```
items = ['age', 'weight', 'score']
pd.Panel(dict(zip(items, [concated.pivot(index='date', columns='id', values=i) for i in items])))
```

This is so nicely specified in this [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean `pd.Panel(dict(zip(items, [df.pivot(index='date', columns='id', values=[ i for i in items])])))`? But I got an error: `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`. Do you have any idea about that? Thanks !

Comment: I mean with the `dict`, yes. I forgot the `dict`, but I edited when I realized. Did it work with the `dict`?

Comment: Can you have a check on the brackets in your code? Cause I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` while copy your code exactly

Comment: Yes there is a closing bracket after `values=i` that I missed. Thanks. Can you check now?

Comment: Yes, the syntax error has gone. But I got this error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` Cause the `date` column has duplicate values.

Comment: How do you want to deal with the duplicate values? Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I have fixed this problem already. And you solution really works! Tons of thanks!