# Reading binary file with specific sequence in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binary

I have some `32x32x8192` binary datafile with a specific sequence and I was wondering.
How I can read it as so in `Python 3x.` The file consists of `Nx × Ny × Nz` numbers (floating point single precision).
 The sequence of the numbers corresponds to `indexes x, y and z` which all increase sequentially from `1 to Nx, Ny and Nz` respectively.
 The fastest-varying index is `z`, followed by `y`, and the slowest varying index is `x`.
That is, the first `Nz` numbers from the sequence correspond to indexes `x = 1, y = 1`, and `z` increasing from `1 to Nz`.

A sample of the data by `np.fromfile("turbine_32x32x8192.bin", dtype=float, count=10, sep="")`:

```
[ -8.26325563e+02  -7.41263867e+00  -1.52541103e+01  -1.83999292e+03
  -7.53629982e+03  -3.43120688e+05  -1.88674962e+04  -1.81482768e+00
  -4.13878029e+03  -8.29483377e+05]
```

Comment: Alright. What did you do about it? Do you have a package you want to use, for example, `numpy`? Do you know how to read files into the package you choose? Did you try to implement it yourself? If the answer to any of those questions is negative, please work on it, get truly stuck then ask. It is daunting to begin something new, but things are fairly easy.

Comment: I have read the file with: np.fromfile("turbine_32x32x8192.bin", dtype=float, count=-1, sep=""). But i want to create a format with 3 columns each named Nx, Ny and Nz, maybe in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Ok. How is the data in your file? From your question I assume you have `Nx` number of files, each with `Nz x Ny` rows and columns. If that is the case, you will have to read the data in loops and append as you go. Try using `np.zeros((Nx, Ny, Nz))` as an initializing matrix. Read a file, and store it in the array, one `Nx` at a time in a loop.

Comment: If you want to read it in pandas, you will still need a loop. However, I don't know of a pandas method that can read a binary file, unless it is a csv binary file. If it is based on csv, you could try `[pd.read_csv(file) for file in files]` to get a list of DataFrames containing all files. This list, you can [convert to a Panel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38886856/3765319) or you can [concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to get a bigger DataFrame will all values in it.

Comment: When reading the binary file it's not structured but just a list.

Comment: I apologize, because I don't work with binary files and I have no idea about them. If you can edit your question and paste a sample of the data returned by `np.fromfile("turbine_32x32x8192.bin", dtype=float, count=-1, sep="")` I would be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
import struct

data = open(filename, 'rb').read()

def chunk(i, j):
    at = i * 32 + j
    return data[at * (8192 * 4) : (at + 1) * (8192 * 4)]

a = [list(struct.unpack('8192f', chunk(i, j))) for i in range(32) for j in range(32)]
```

the result will be in `a`.